# Truth function question

Tags: symbolic-logic

Is there a truth function connective for the phrase “after all”

I know “all”  can be done in finite cases

I am using the Logic Book 4th ed
I am trying to find a paraphrase for it.

Comment: After all is an English language phrase, no mathematical or logical meaning. "After all is said and done," or, "Well he's just doing what comes naturally, after all."

Comment: That is what I thought

Comment: "After all," as a phrase in English is a [transition phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_(linguistics)) and like some transition words may have some logical import depending on context.

Comment: Thanks the clarification.